# Dropzone.js max file size unit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
$scope.dropzoneConfig = {
    dictRemoveFileConfirmation: CONST.ARE_YOU_SURE,
    parallelUploads: 3,
    maxFileSize: 30
}
```

I have dropzone with config JSON as shown above.

Can somebody please tell me what is the unit of `maxFileSize` property? Is it 30 MB??

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration

Comment: The max file size is in `MiB` https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/options.js#L84

Answer (score 3):

According documentation it's 30 MB

Comment: Funnily enough the documentation currently says it's in bytes. It also says that the default is 256 so that's proooobably incorrect.

The docblock in the source code says it's MiB. https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/options.js

Comment: This has got to be some kind of typo in the docs.  I had it set to `10` and was uploading files much larger than 10 bytes.